# Powershell - Working with Get-StorageGroupCopyStatus from a variable

Tags: variables, powershell

I need your help working with a variable in Powershell.

I want to put the result of Get-StorageGroupCopyStatus in a variable and then be able to work with the parameters from the result.

When I execute

```
Get-StorageGroupCopyStatus -Server server -StandbyMachine standbyserver
```

it returns several properties like "Name", "SummaryCopyStatus, "CopyQueueLength", and others.
The thing is that I would like to be able to manipulate those properties through a variable in order to be able to use it in a IF statement, like this:

```
$st = Get-StorageGroupCopyStatus -Server server -StandbyMachine standbyserver

if ($st.SummaryCopyStatus -NotMatch "Healthy")
```

What's happening is that the parameter ".SummaryCopyStatus" cannot be obtained through the variable "$st".

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably get back a collection of objects and you need to process each one, one at a time. Get the storge groups object, filter out the ones that don't match your qriteria and then do something on the ones that passed the filtering.

```
Get-StorageGroupCopyStatus -Server server -StandbyMachine standbyserver | 
Where-Object { $_.SummaryCopyStatus -NotMatch "Healthy" } |
Foreach-Object { "do you stuff here" }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, but I can't test it:

```
$Serv = Get-StorageGroupCopyStatus -Server server -StandbyMachine standbyserver

$data = @()

foreach ($item in $serv)
{
$obj = new-object psObject
$obj | Add-Member -membertype noteproperty -name "Name" -Value $item.StorageGroupName
$obj | Add-Member -membertype noteproperty -name "CopyStatus -Value $item.SummaryCopyStatus
$obj | Add-Member -membertype noteproperty -name "CopyQueueLength" -Value $item.CopyQueueLength
$data += $obj
}

$data # contains the properties you added before.
```